# is there something wrong with the server configuration?

Tags: php, sql, ajax, caching

hello there ive created a site that have the pagination using ajax request to change its content using ajax that request sql data and print it to html codes.

the first site : pilem21.com

this one work just fine,

but the second site wont work as i hoped.

the second site : nontonoke.com

is the anything wrong with the server? or is it on my code?

here is the example of my codes requesting the pagination data

```
      var a = $(".film2numb").val();
  return $.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : "php/controller1.php?page=semuafilm",
    data : "data="+a,
    success: function(data){
      $('.semuafilm').load('php/film.php',function(){$("img.lazy").lazyload();});
    },
  });
```

Comment: You need to give more info about what you are trying to achieve and the type of error you are getting , I think this can help.

Comment: im trying to make the pagination works the same as the first site,

but on on the second site it wont work the same as the first site, the database and the code are the exact same code, both.

the the difference is the first site using nginx and second using varnish

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? SQL is just the **query language** - not a concrete database product. Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.